# Tooltip Title , how to set the title as field value instead of hard coded value in vegalite charts

Tags: vega-lite

In Vegalite for tooltip, how to set data value as Title

When i set data field in the title it does not work, below is code snippet

```
"tooltip": [
  {

    "field" : "xToolTip",
    
    "title" : "xName"
    
  }
```

where xName is data attribute

[Tooltip image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4oy6.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't set a title at all and the title will be the name of the field in your dataset.